# Finding solution of first order non linear equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have $$m\frac{dv}{dt}=mg-kv^2$$

and I want to find v(t). I tried to separate the derivative over both sides but I am getting no where. At the moment I have

$$v+\frac{v^2}{gt}=\frac{kt}{m}$$

Can someone please detail how to solve this

Answer (score 2):

well, you can write your equation as follows

$$ \frac{ \mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t} = g - \frac{k}{m} v^2 \iff \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{g - \frac{k}{m} v^2} = \mathrm{d}t \iff \int \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{g - \frac{k}{m} v^2} = t + C $$

To sove the integral, write $$ \frac{k}{m} v^2 = \left( \sqrt{ \frac{k}{m}} v \right)^2 $$

and put $ z = \sqrt{ \frac{k}{m}} v \implies \mathrm{d}z = \sqrt{ \frac{k}{m}} \mathrm{d}v $
Hence your integral become

$$   \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}} \int \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{g - z^2}$$

I will solve the integral  for the general case, and then it should easy for you to solve the required integral:

$$ \int \frac{ \mathrm{d}x}{a^2 - x^2 } = \int \frac{ \mathrm{d} x}{(a-x)(a+x)} = \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2a(a-x)} - \int \frac{ \mathrm{d}x}{2a(a+x)} = \frac{1}{2a} \ln \left( \frac{a-x}{a+x} \right) + K$$

Comment: So what is v(t)?

Comment: @user88720. Did you compute the last nice integral provided by Lemur ? It would be good you show us some work (8 minutes between Lemur's good answer and your next request is not very long).

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how to. Sorry

Comment: I have included details. Just choose $a = \sqrt{g} $ and you are done.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow at all. Where did the square root come from? Mind you I am a first year just out of high school. Some steps are not so obvious to me

Comment: Again, I'm sorry but I don't follow. I really just need to know what v(t) is. But I've come to the conclusion that I'm not going to be able to work it out. It's the last question of the assignment but I'll just have to skip it

Comment: Hint: $a=\sqrt{g},\ x=\sqrt{k/m}v$, just substitute and remember that RHS is $t-t_0$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
m\frac{dv}{dt}&=mg-kv^2\\
m\frac{dv}{mg-kv^2}&=dt\\
\frac1g\int\frac{dv}{1-\dfrac k{mg} v^2}&=\int\ dt\\
\frac1g\int\frac{dv}{1-a^2v^2}&=\int\ dt\quad\Rightarrow\quad a^2=\dfrac k{mg}\\
\frac1{2g}\left(\int\frac{dv}{1+av}+\int\frac{dv}{1-av}\right)&=\int\ dt\\
\frac1{2g}\left(\ln(1+av)-\ln(1-av)\right)&=t+C_1\\
\ln\left(\frac{1+av}{1-av}\right)&=2gt+C_2\quad\Rightarrow\quad C_2=2gC_1\\
\frac{1+av}{1-av}&=e^{\large 2gt+C_2}\\
\frac{1+av}{1-av}&=Ke^{\large 2gt}\quad\Rightarrow\quad K=e^{\large C_2}\\
1+av&=Ke^{\large 2gt}-aKe^{\large 2gt}v\\
av+aKe^{\large 2gt}v&=Ke^{\large 2gt}-1\\
\left(Ke^{\large 2gt}+1\right)av&=Ke^{\large 2gt}-1\\
v&=\frac{Ke^{\large 2gt}-1}{a\left(Ke^{\large 2gt}+1\right)}\\
v(t)&=\sqrt{\frac{mg}{k}}\left(\frac{Ke^{\large 2gt}-1}{Ke^{\large 2gt}+1}\right).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Line 5. Shouldn't the `2` be in the numerator?

Comment: @stackErr No. It's correct.